# Make sections individually toggleable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I cannot use a parent toggle component (I tried, its because I have only code to pass and that doesnt work), but I need to `show` and `!show` individual unique product sections. I tried with `key` and `id` but not working. How to tie the toggle to each individual unique product section so that not all sections toggle at the same time? Basically `socks` and `shoes` are toggle-able, open/close, but when you click one of them then both open (and close).

```
<script>
   const show = ref(false);
</script>
```

and

```
const products = {
  "socks": {
    "socksblack": "/socksblack",
    "sockswhite": "/sockswhite",
    },
  "shirts": "/shirts",
  "bags": "/bags",
  "shoes": {
    "shoes4men": "/shoes4men",
    "shoes4women": "/shoes4women",
    }
```

My code:

```
<div v-for="(product, link) in links" :key="link" class="">
  <template v-if="isObject(link)">
    <div>
      <a href="product" @click="show = !show">{{ link }}</a>
        <div v-show="show" :key="link"><!-- I tried to put :key here and also on the @click event but not working--->
        <!-- the product subcategories -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `link` in `show` variable, instead of boolean:

```js
const { ref, reactive } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const products = reactive({
      "socks": { "socksblack": "/socksblack", "sockswhite": "/sockswhite", },
      "shirts": "/shirts",
      "bags": "/bags",
      "shoes": { "shoes4men": "/shoes4men", "shoes4women": "/shoes4women", }
    })
    const show = ref(null)
    return { show, products }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(product, link) in products" :key="link" class="">
    <a href="product" @click.prevent="show = link">{{ link }}</a>
    <div v-show="show === link">{{ product }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```